# Python: substring existence

Tags: python, string, list

I have an HTML scraper that parses a particular set of sites to get the names of products being sold. If the product is in our whitelist, we process it differently than a product that isn't.
Now the scraper returns the whole name of the product. It could be 'Nike Air Jordan' or 'Air Jordan by Nike' or 'LunarEpic by Nike' and so on, but Nike is in our whitelist.
So what I'm doing now is a simple or check:

```
>>> product_name = get_prod_name(url)
>>> if 'Nike' in product_name:
       do_process()
```

Now we've got a list of these whitelisted products, such as ['Nike', 'Reebok', 'Adidas'... ]
Is there a better way of performing this check, other than

```
if 'Nike' in product_name or 'Reebok' in product_name or 'Adidas' in product_name
```

?
Tx,Craig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the builtin `any` function:

```
products = ['Nike', 'Reebok', 'Adidas', ...]
if any(product in product_name for product in products):
    ...
```

The other alternative is to use regular expressions:

```
regex = '|'.join(re.escape(product) for product in products))
if re.search(regex, product_name):
   ...
```

But that's almost certainly overkill ...

Answer (score 2):

you may be looking for the `any()` function with a generator comprehension

```
if any(product in product_name for product in ['Nike', 'Reebok', 'Adidas']):
```